# GCC compiler on Jailbroken AppleTV compiling error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, signals

Ok so I think this is probably out of the ballpark for most people here (including me :P ) but here's my problem...

I am trying to get together a basic compiling toolchain for an AppleTV 3rd gen. After a very long time of digging through archives and source code I got a decent set of tools together. (csu, gdb, gcc, headfile, ldid, real-libgcc!, make, odcctools, uuid, file, rsync, autoconf, gawk, python, coreutils, inetutils, git, less, nano, gettext) and while most of them are outdated they still operate decently. All except for gcc. Great, eh? So my problem is whenever I compile ANY C code, even something as simple as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
printf("Hello World!\n");
return 0;
}
```

it will always return `Killed: 9`, I don't understand why it would do this but I do know that it means the program was killed with the signal 9 which terminates a process instantly no matter what. However I am very new to C in general and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
A\\/.

P.S here is the output from `uname -a`

```
Darwin Apple-TV 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Jan 29 18:51:13 PST 2021; root:xnu-2784.40.6~93/MarijuanARM_S5L8947X AppleTV3,2 arm J33iAP Darwin
```

Comment: What if you simply invoke `gcc` or `gcc --version` or `gcc -v` ? BTW, what is the point of running the tools on the TV itself? If you want to program it, use a cross-compiler.

Comment: Apple-TV:~ root# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5555)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: please enlighten me, what is this cross-compiler? Can I compile for the appletv from my computer? its a MacBook Air.

Comment: Yes, this is what cross-compiler does. It runs on a host of architecture A and produces binaries for target architecture B.

Comment: I'm not developing an actual GUI app for it, I jailbroke the AppleTV and I am trying to install packages from source code but I didn't know that cross-compiling was a thing so I was trying to get a native compiler on the actual device.

Comment: Anyway, try seeing on which stage it is being killed. Run it with verbose mode `gcc -v program.c`

Comment: I just ran the command and I didn't see any errors. Is there anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: I have no idea why GCC would kill itself with `KILL` (signal #9), so we might think which other process wants to do that, and why. Perhaps memory allocation problem, caught by the operating system? GCC tends to use lots of memory.